# How can I render multiple components while looping through an object and then interpolate the JSX associated?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, jsx

I am working on a website that scrapes data from NYT's API. I have all the data necessary already(JPG image links, links to the articles, titles to articles, and the dates). I am trying to create multiple divs and store the info I have into each of its own containers like this:
[image]

The problem arises when I try to render the info using forEach or map and it displays it all into one container instead of creating its own container with its own unique info. All the arrays are ordered so all I would need to do is to loop through each array like this:

( **Container 1:** postNY.images[0],postNY.links[0],postNY.titles[0],postNY.sections[0], postNY.dates[0], postNY.summaries[0])

( **Container 2:** postNY.images[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmzLT.png),postNY.links[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmzLT.png),postNY.titles[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmzLT.png),postNY.sections[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmzLT.png), postNY.dates[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmzLT.png), postNY.summaries[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmzLT.png))

ETC. until I've reached the highest index of images

and then display that info into each of their own div containers I've styled.

Here is the code where the problem is occurring:

```
const renderEverything = () => {
        const renderImgs = postNY.images
        const renderSummaries = postNY.summaries
        const renderLinks = postNY.links
        const renderTitles = postNY.titles
        const renderDates = postNY.dates
        const renderSections = postNY.sections

        const renderEvery = renderImgs.map((elem) =>
        <div className="container">
                {renderImgs[0]}
                {renderSummaries[0]}
                {renderLinks[0]}
                {renderTitles[0]}
                {renderDates[0]}
                {renderSections[0]}
        </div>
        )
        
        return (
            <div>
                {renderEvery}
            </div>
        )
        
    }
```

Here is the full code:

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import '../PageContent/PageContent.css'
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faThumbsUp, faHeart} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'



const PageContent = (props) => {


    const [postNY, setPostNY] = useState({
        images: [],
        links: [],
        titles: [],
        sections: [],
        dates: [],
        summaries: []
    })


    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://api.nytimes.com/svc/mostpopular/v2/viewed/1.json?api-key=uCErKitNpdG7E7ma9rT0IxEGZ4xKs8Vw")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((objArr)=>{

            // GET IMG
            var imgs = []
             for (var key in Object.entries(objArr)[3][1]) {
                var obj = Object.entries(objArr)[3][1][key]
                Object.entries(obj['media']).forEach(elem => 
                {
                    imgs.push(elem[1]['media-metadata'][2].url)
                }
                    ) 
            }
            
             // GET LINKS
            var urls = []
            Object.entries(objArr)[3][1].forEach(elem => urls.push(elem.url))
            

            // GET TITLES
            var titles = []
            Object.entries(objArr)[3][1].forEach(elem => titles.push(elem.title))
            

            // GET SECTION TAG
            var sections = []
            Object.entries(objArr)[3][1].forEach(elem => sections.push(elem.section))
            
            
            // GET PUBLISHED DATE
            var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
            var dates = []
            Object.entries(objArr)[3][1].forEach(elem => 
               { 
                   var myDate  = new Date(elem.published_date); 
                   dates.push(myDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options))
                }
                )
            

            // GET BRIEF SUMMARIES
            var summaries = []
            Object.entries(objArr)[3][1].forEach(elem => summaries.push(elem.abstract));
            
            setPostNY({
                images: imgs,
                links: urls,
                titles: titles,
                sections: sections,
                dates: dates,
                summaries: summaries
            })
        })
        
        
    }, [])

    const renderEverything = () => {
        const renderImgs = postNY.images
        const renderSummaries = postNY.summaries
        const renderLinks = postNY.links
        const renderTitles = postNY.titles
        const renderDates = postNY.dates
        const renderSections = postNY.sections

        const renderEvery = renderImgs.map((elem) =>
        <div className="container">
                {renderImgs[0]}
                {renderSummaries[0]}
                {renderLinks[0]}
                {renderTitles[0]}
                {renderDates[0]}
                {renderSections[0]}
        </div>
        )
        
        return (
            <div>
                {renderEvery}
            </div>
        )
        
    }
        
        
        

        
        
        
    
    

    return (
        <div className="page-content">
            
            {renderEverything()}
            
        </div>
        
    )
}

export default PageContent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error, you need to use i instead of 0.

```
const renderEverything = () => {
        const renderImgs = postNY.images
        const renderSummaries = postNY.summaries
        const renderLinks = postNY.links
        const renderTitles = postNY.titles
        const renderDates = postNY.dates
        const renderSections = postNY.sections

        const renderEvery = renderImgs.map((elem, i) =>
        <div className="container">
                {renderImgs[i]}
                {renderSummaries[i]}
                {renderLinks[i]}
                {renderTitles[i]}
                {renderDates[i]}
                {renderSections[i]}
        </div>
        )
        
        return (
            <div>
                {renderEvery}
            </div>
        )
        
    }
```